# Error: Cannot use post method in jsp

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using `method="post"` for form submission in jsp page.

```
<form action="addpost.do" method ="post">
<input type="hidden" value="anuj" name="myname" >
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

In the form I am passing two values in hidden fields and getting these values in java.But on form submission error is coming that you cannot use GET method.

In my java file required action has post method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addpost", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a JSP-servlet use the `doPost(...){...}` in servlet.

If its a spring-mvc then

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

The above line has to used for receiving the request as POST in the Controller class.

Comment: Post your 1.code 2. Technologies used. So that you might be guided in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code , that I tested is ok just now .
Here is my code :

jsp pages:

```
<form action="<%=basePath%>index/testGet" method="get">
        <input value="111" name="testTxt" type="hidden" >
        <input type="submit" value="testGet" >
</form>
```

springMVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testGet")
public String testGet(String testTxt){
    System.out.print("testTxt:");
    System.out.println(testTxt);
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

and the console's log :

```
testTxt:111
```

My English is bad , Forgive me.

Comment: In mine case i am using "POST" as method and getting error that i can't use get method because in my spring i mapped my function to receive POST.

Answer (score 0):

I think your form action url isn't mapped to the url in your requestmapping.
Try the following:

```
<c:url value="/addpost" var="addPost"/>
<form action="${addPost}" method="POST">
```

Which should generate the correct url for you. Don't forget to include the taglib on top of your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Also check if your controller has a requestmapping annotation, in which case it should be included in the c:url value.